# How to deploy my asp.net project in IIS?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have windows 2003 server , and a asp.net project developed in VS2008 developer edition

how to deploy this website in the server?

Answer (score 3):

Would it not be easier to just use the Publish Website option in Visual Studio? Its under the Build Menu.

Ensure you have installed IIS and you can copy via Visual Studio all the relevant files associated with your site.

James.

Comment: How to check iis is installed ??

Comment: I am pretty sure Windows Server 2003 is enabled by default, however, to double check just make sure you have the following directory:

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot

And also try to navigate via the browser to http:\\localhost, the default web page should appear. If it doesn't, then you will have to check your configuration, otherwise you are good to go :)

Comment: I meant to say "I am pretty sure IIS is installed and enabled by default on Windows Server 2003"...

Comment: Oops its not there .. my security team desabled it .. :-(

Comment: You can renable IIS through IIS Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Installer XML ([WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)) as it is highly configurable and very similar to the new setup projects in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the files into a folder on the server. Right click the folder and go into Sharing ans Security. Click the tab Web sharing and Share the folder. Choose which web site to add the project to. That *should* work I think. You can now open IIS and see if your site is in there. Access it using the URL in there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a web setup and deployment package. Especially if you have used something like Crsytal Reports that has complicated dependencies.